# take the snapshot of page in textual format in angularjs app

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui

If I have a webpage with content like this:
    `<ul>`
     `<li ng-show="showthis">{{message1}}</li>`
     `<li ng-hide="hidethis">{{message2}}</li>`
     `<li >{{message3}}</li>`
    `</ul>`

And I set the model for 'message' such that

```
$scope.message1, $scope.message2 and $scope.message3 are the text entered by user from inputbox.
$scope.showthis = 0
$scope.hidethis = 1
```

Then on the screen, the contents of the div will display depending upon values of **inputs.showthis** and **inputs.hidethis**

Is there any way to store the text visible  on the screen in a variable. For example for the above case I will have following text in a variable.

```
Item1
```

Basically I want to take the snapshot of the page in textual format and save it in a variable to mail the content while a button (mail the text) is clicked.

Can any one  please tell me the possible approach to achieve above. ?

Comment: Wouldn't "Item3" be visible as well?  Regardless, I think you are going to have a method on the on-click event for mail to evaluate the state of the variables you care about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem starts in the way you represent your data (messages):

- `message1, message2, message3` : better go with an array..
- `showthis, hidethis` : that's wrong, polluting the code with obscure variable names .

#### Store the messages within array of message objects.

```js
$scope.messages = [
  {text: 'Item1' , visible: false},
  {text: 'Item2' , visible: false},
  {text: 'Item3' , visible: true}
]
```

#### Iterate all messages and show only visible messages

```html
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-show="message.visible">
      <input type="text" ng-model="message.text">
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### Finally, we can filter all visible messages ans show their text joined.

```js
$scope.getVisible = function(){
  return $scope.messages.filter(function(msg){
    return msg.visible;
  }).map(function(msg){
    return msg.text;
  }).join(',');
}
```

Comment: @IIan Thanks, that might help.

Comment: @IIan please update your answer for the when text is not a fixed string but is a variable.

Comment: what do you mean by "the when text"?

Comment: @llan  please update your answer when "text" is not a fixed string but is a variable. I have edited the question.